# Blur the set of values in Dojo 1.6 filteringselect

Tags: dojo

How can i blur particular set of values on filteringselect in dojo 1.6.  I need to blue set of values from the dropdown, so that the user can see those options and can't choose

Answer (score 0):

sorry... blur or blue? do you mean that you want to change the appearance of some particular cases among the options listed by your FilteringSelect? I can help you, but I don't fully understand your question. Are you loading the options from a dojo store? writing them as markup, or adding them using the addOption() method?